# AttachDBFilename and synonyms

Tags: c#, database, synonym

I have two databases files *.mdf I connect to them with AttachDBFilename connection string property. But, for some reason I can't use synonyms to ref other databases it seems that AttachDBFilename creates isolated database is there some hack that I can use to resolve this issue?

```
Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;Initial Catalog=Data1;Integrated Security=true;AttachDBFilename=data1.mdf 

Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;Initial Catalog=Data2;Integrated Security=true;AttachDBFilename=data2.mdf
```

Answer (score 0):

> it seems that AttachDBFilename creates isolated database

Yes.

LocalDB is there for *simple* scenarios.

> is there some hack that i can use to resolve this issue?

I don't think so.

If LocalDB is no longer sufficient for your requirements, then switch to SQL Express (or other edition) that meets your needs.